# Firefox HTTP Form Action doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, asp-classic

In Chrome and IE, the following code, when the Anchor tag is clicked, pops up the form (modal box ID of "modalContent", form ID of "DL") and adds an "OnSubmit" to the Form. When the Form is submitted, it will navigate to the requested PDF via Javascript, and run some ASP to send an email with their details attached.

```
<script language="javascript">
            function downloadAnyway(link) {
                    $('#DL')[0].setAttribute('ONSUBMIT', 'return checkform("' + link + '")'); 
                    $('#modalContent').modal();
            }

            function checkform(navName) {
                    window.open(navName);
                    $.modal.close();
            }
</script>    

<!-- link to download a product guide -->    
<a href='javascript:downloadAnyway("downloads/ProductGuide.pdf")');">Product Guide</a>

<div id="modalContent">           
            <form id="DL" action="contactusprocessNew2.asp" method="post" name="contact" >
                <div align="center">
                     <input type="image" src="templates/default/images/submit_download.gif" class="imagebutton" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome, in Firefox, the Javascript onsubmit works, but the action of the asp never fires. If I remove the javascript, the asp fires as expected.

So, the final form in FireFox, after the "onsubmit" has been dynamically added looks as below:

```
<form id="DL" action="contactusprocessNew2.asp" method="post" name="contact" onsubmit="return checkform("downloads/ProductGuide.pdf")">
```

The onsubmit fires, opening the product guide in another tab, however, the ASP Action never fires. There is more that goes on here, like we write a cookie making sure we don't ask the client for a download every time they use our downloads, however, I've trimmed off anything I think is outside the problem domain.

In the asp, I have gotten rid of all code and put a simple response.redirect to see if it fires and make sure nothing is going on in the ASP.

Any idea how I can get this to function in FireFox?

**UPDATE:**

I have replaced the onsubmit event wireup with a 'proper' jquery submit wireup replacing the first line below, with the second. The asp on the form still does not function.

```
    //$('#DL')[0].setAttribute('ONSUBMIT', 'return checkform(\'' + link + '\')');

    $('#DL').submit(function checkform() {
        $.modal.close();
        window.open(link);
        return true;
    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

Right, it is because to modal popup CLOSES before the ASP fires. If we comment out the line $.modal.close(); then the asp fires as expected. In Chrome and IE the javascript and the ASP must fire at the same time, in Firefox, the javascript fires which "hides" the div with the "modelContent" and the asp can no longer fire. So this is the real problem... now how to sort it out...

Comment: Mismatched quotes? should be `onsubmit="return checkform('downloads/ProductGuide.pdf')">` ditto for `downloadAnyway`

Comment: shouldn't your method checkform return true or false?

Comment: That's really the wrong way to set up event handlers.

Comment: Tried changing the quotes and returning true, no luck. What would you suggest @Pointy?

Comment: Well you're using jQuery - set up the event handler the proper way, via the jQuery ".submit()" method.

Comment: @Pointy please see the update, the asp still doesn't fire after this tidy up.

Comment: I don't understand why are you doing that to simply send a mail and download a pdf, why don't make the asp forces a download?